# Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Tags: php

I have a question about PHP error. I went through other similar questions, and apply it, but I still have a problem like this, so I am asking it.

Situation is like this. There is an text box called special instruction; if I put just one line it is fine to work, but if I put more than one line it causes problem like this. I put urlencode(str) to solve the problem, but it is still showed up. What do I need to change? T.T

error message is "Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected."

```
if($_POST['Submit'] == 'Submit Order'){
    $today = date('D M dY');
    $to_time = date('h:i a');
    $hours = substr($to_time, 0, -6);
    $minutes = substr($to_time, -5, 2);
    $seconds = substr($to_time, -2);
    $total_seconds = ($hours * 3600) + ($minutes * 60) + $seconds;

    $date123 = $_POST['day'];
    $date_post = date('D M dY',$date123);

    $time_post = $_POST['time']; 
    $hours_post   = substr($time_post, 0, -6);
    $minutes_post = substr($time_post, -5, 2);
    $seconds_post = substr($time_post, -2);
    $total_seconds_post = ($hours_post * 3600) + ($minutes_post * 60) + $seconds_post;

    $tip_amo = $_POST["tip_amount"];
    $deliv_mails = $_POST["deliv_mails"];
    $coupon_no = $_POST['coupon_no'];
    $minorder = $_POST['minorder'];
    $subtotal_amount = $_POST['subtotal_amount'];
    $payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
    $comments = addslashes($_POST['comments']);
    $coupon_code = $_REQUEST["coupon_code"];
    $customer_comments = get_field(CART,"additional_text","session_id='$sessionid'");

    if($comments == ''){
        $comments1 = $customer_comments;
    }else{
        $comments1 = $comments;
    }

    if($time_post!='') {
        if($today==$date_post){
            $query = [
                'day' => $date123,
                'time' => $time_post,
                'coupon_no' => $coupon_no,
                'minorder' => $minorder,
                'subtotal_amount' => $subtotal_amount,
                'payment_type' => $payment_type,
                'comments' => $comments1,
                'coupon_code' => $coupon_code,
                'tip_amount' => $tip_amo,
                'deliv_mails' => $deliv_mails,
                'd' => $address
            ];
            header('Location: details_info_order.php?' . http_build_query($query));
            exit;
        }else{
            $query = [
                'day' => $date123,
                'time' => $time_post,
                'coupon_no' => $coupon_no,
                'minorder' => $minorder,
                'subtotal_amount' => $subtotal_amount,
                'payment_type' => $payment_type,
                'comments' => $comments1,
                'coupon_code' => $coupon_code,
                'tip_amount' => $tip_amo,
                'deliv_mails' => $deliv_mails,
                'd' => $address
            ];
            header('Location: details_info_order.php?' . http_build_query($query));
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

> Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected. in /home4/mikehan2/public_html/mikehan7/final_checkout_block.php on line 64

it is the exact error message.

Comment: did you format the code for SO? the text must be in a single ugly long line (cannot use line breaks to improve readability in header).

Comment: haha... I know it is in an ugly single line...

Comment: You can't use `urlencode()` within a string like that

Comment: @Phil What do I need to use? T.T

Comment: @phil you are right. urlencode is a function and cannot be used in string concentration like that.

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon at the end of the `$query` array. This code would not parse correctly and there's no way it would generate the error you're reporting. Please post the **real** code the the **complete error message**

Comment: @Phil Thank you again. I put real php code and the complete error message. I just copy and paste it.

Comment: @BryanK. Which is line #64 and what version of PHP are you using? You should also have error reporting turned up for development. Set `display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL` in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: @Phil I am actually using PHP 5.2.17 and display_errors was on and error_reporting was not E_ALL ,but 6135.

Comment: #64 is header('Location: details_info_order.php?' . http_build_query($query1));. This part.

Comment: You shouldn't just copy code and expect it to work without reading it. You'll need to use the legacy array syntax. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Phil I fixed the problem. I removed the addslashes from $comments=addslashes($_POST['comments']); and it works. Thanks for helping me :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should really use something like [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query); no need to manually URL encode and no messy string concatenation, eg

```
$query = array(
    'day' => $date123,
    'time' => $time_post,
    // etc
);
header('Location: details_info_order.php?' . http_build_query($query));
exit;
```

Comment: I still have a same problem on different line number, but Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @BryanK. Please edit your question with your updated code as well as the exact and complete details of the error message.

Comment: @BryanK. Why did you accept this answer if your code still doesn't work?

Comment: @BryanK. Obviously the short array syntax is only going to work in PHP  5.4 or later. I've revised my answer based on your clarification of PHP version.

Comment: this one is also not working, I am looking somewhere else to change. I hope there is problem such as if I put comments in two different row, it produce two different comments to conflict. I have no idea...

Answer (score 1):

Some of your variables contains a multiline text, maybe COMMENTS.
Use `urlencode`:

```
'comments' => urlencode($comments1),
...
```